# Trouble with TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK scope

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How are these two statements different with regard to locking the table:

```
-- Variation 1

BEGIN TRAN

-- Lock the table explicitly via a SELECT
DECLARE @TempId BIGINT=(SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TargetTable WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK));

-- Then perform DML operations
MERGE TargetTable as target
USING (...) AS source
ON (target.Id=source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ... ;

DELETE FROM Target
WHERE Id=...

COMMIT TRAN
```

As compared to:

```
-- Variation 2

BEGIN TRAN

-- Lock the table as part of the first DML operation
MERGE TargetTable WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK) as target
USING (...) AS source
ON (target.Id=source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ... ;

DELETE FROM Target
WHERE Id=...

COMMIT TRAN
```

The same table is getting a TABLOCKX put on it in both cases, but with Variation 2, I get a deadlock when multiple sessions concurrently execute this code. With Variation 1, I do not. I thought the two would work identically, but apparently there is some difference in how the lock TABLOCKX is acquired or how long it is held.

Could some knowledgeable person please shed some light on this.

Comment: You can trace locks taken in Profiler or using `TF 1200` to investigate yourself...